# PostgreSQL - How to create an integer array from a select to pass as an argument to a function

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a function that receives an `integer[]` array as a parameter.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_master_products(P_PRODUCTS_IDS integer[])
  RETURNS SETOF record
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$
DECLARE
    CURRENT_ID integer;
    PRODUCT RECORD;
    COMPONENT1 RECORD;
    COMPONENT2 RECORD;
    COMPONENT3 RECORD;
BEGIN
....

END;
```

And when I call this function I have to do it like this:

```
SELECT
    "ID",
    "CODE",
    "CODE2",
    "NAME",
    "COMPOSERS",
    "PTYPE_ID",
    "PTYPE_NAME",
    "COMPONENT_QUANTITY",
    "UM_ID",
    "LEVEL"
FROM 
    get_master_products(array[ 20, 40, 50, 80])
AS
    (
      "ID" integer,
      "CODE" varchar,
      "CODE2" varchar,
      "NAME" varchar,
      "COMPOSERS" numeric,
      "PTYPE_ID" bigint,
      "PTYPE_NAME" varchar,
      "COMPONENT_QUANTITY" numeric,
      "UM_ID" varchar,
      "LEVEL" varchar
    );
```

but is there a way to do something like this to call the function?:

```
get_master_products(array[ (SELECT id, FROM products WHERE composers > 0) ])
```

to automatically create the pass array with a SQL query??

Can you help me please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html):

```
get_master_products(SELECT array_agg(id) FROM products WHERE composers > 0)
```